# Facebook Graph determine if user likes object

Tags: facebook-graph-api

By querying fbid/likes i can get the fbid and names of all of the users who likes an object. However, when me myself likes the object, i represent a page, and therefore my "like" isn't presented as me, but as the page. How can i determine if the user likes an object or not?

Comment: as not an answer, but qualification: after you use method `"POST objectID/likes"` or `"DELETE objectID/likes"`, facebook return you result like `"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT = true (or false)"` BUT! you really can't see, if you already like this object or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research i found that i simply can't. The best way is to query the Graph for the users who like the object, and then compare that to the user id and see if the user id exists in the result